# What are the differences between Ghazawat and a Saraya?

Tags: prophet-muhammad, war

I have read in a [fatwa from Islamweb.com](http://fatwa.islamweb.net/) that the Prophet Muhammad conducted  expeditions against the Kuffar. Some of these expeditions are called *Ghazawat* and some are called *Saraya*.

I'd like to know what is the difference between these two types of expeditions.

Answer (score 3):

Both *ghazawat* (sing. *ghazwah*) and *saraya* (sing. *sariyyah*) are types of expeditions, some military, some diplomatic, some economic, etc. An expedition in which the Prophet (saws) personally participated (i.e. travelled with) is called a *ghazwah* and an expedition that he (saws) ordered but didn't personally participate in it and rather appointed others to lead is called a *sariyyah*.

Source: Any seerah book.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is as it seems the following:

- A Ghazwa is a expedition/battle/rencounter the Messenger of Allah (peace be upon him) assists him self. And it doesn't matter whether he fought or not!
- A sariya: is a expedition/battle/rencounter where the Messenger of Allah (peace be upon him) only sent his sahaba (may Allah be pleased with them) out without going/participating himself!

See the following [Fatwa](http://fatwa.islamweb.net/fatwa/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=615)